# @set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchRequest) and @set_ev_cls(event.EventLinkRequest) meaning in Python

Tags: python, networking, openflow

I am trying to understand the two functions in Python.It comes from the code for ryu opensource controller.I suspect it somehow implements LLDP and tries to store the topology information.I don't know what

```
 @set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchRequest)
```

and

```
@set_ev_cls(event.EventLinkRequest)
```

I don't know what the above statement means in Python.It would be great if someone could explain the meaning.The whole file is given here.[link to the python source file](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/topology/switches.py#L836)

```
 @set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchRequest)
    def switch_request_handler(self, req):
        # LOG.debug(req)
        dpid = req.dpid

        switches = []
        if dpid is None:
            # reply all list
            for dp in self.dps.itervalues():
                switches.append(self._get_switch(dp.id))
        elif dpid in self.dps:
            switches.append(self._get_switch(dpid))

        rep = event.EventSwitchReply(req.src, switches)
        self.reply_to_request(req, rep)

    @set_ev_cls(event.EventLinkRequest)
    def link_request_handler(self, req):
        # LOG.debug(req)
        dpid = req.dpid

        if dpid is None:
            links = self.links
        else:
            links = [link for link in self.links if link.src.dpid == dpid]
        rep = event.EventLinkReply(req.src, dpid, links)
        self.reply_to_request(req, rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Observe events:
>   A Ryu application can register its interest for a specific type of event by providing a handler method using ryu.controller.handler.set_ev_cls decorator.

visit: http://ryu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ryu_app_api.html

Answer (score 0):

The `@set_event_cls(event.*)` lines are [python decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). There are lots of [resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20decorators) that explain them, so I won't do that here.

In this case they are used to register callbacks for network events. Basically, the `set_event_cls` decorator associates that function (e.g. `switch_request_handler`)  with an event class (e.g. `event.EventSwitchRequest`, so that when Ryu receives an `EventSwitchRequest`, it calls `switch_request_handler` with the request passed as the parameter `req`.

The actual decorator function `set_event_cls()` is defined in [handler.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu/blob/master/ryu/controller/handler.py).